# How to submit a form to ASP.NET Core MVC action method by AngularJs $uibModal

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I developed a model popup in AngularJs, but I don't have any idea how to submit popup form to an ASP.NET Core MVC action method. The application is developed in Visual Studio using .NET Core 7 and AngularJs version is 1.8.3.

Main page:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-app="myApp">
    <div style="margin-top:12px;" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="product in products" style="border:1px solid #333;border-radius:5px;padding:16px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:0;margin-bottom:4px; width: 16.6667%;display:inline-block;" align="center">
            @*  Html body here *@
                <input type="button" id="filterButton" ng-click='open(product)' name="add_to_cart" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-info form-control" value="Add to Cart" />
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    var app = angular.module('myApp');
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal) {
        $scope.id = 0;
        $scope.product = null;
        $scope.products = @Html.Raw(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model));
        $scope.open = function (product) {
            $scope.product = product;
            var modalContent = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: '/Products/AddToCart/' + product.EnID,
                controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                controllerAs: '$ctrl',
                resolve: {
                    product: function () {
                        return $scope.product;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, product) {
        var $ctrl = this;
        $scope.selectedUnitItem = null;
        $scope.inventory = null;
        $scope.productobj = product;
        $ctrl.cancel = function () {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
        $ctrl.ok = function () {
            $uibModalInstance.close();
        };
        $scope.onUnitChanged = function (code) {
            $scope.selectedUnitItem = $scope.productobj.Inventories.find(r => r.Code == code);
        }
    });
</script>
```

`AddToCart.csHtml` page:

```
<form asp-action="PostAddToCart" method="post">
    <div class="modal-header btn-info"> 
        <label class="modal-title control-label col-md-11">Add To Cart</label>
        <label class="modal-title control-label col-md-1" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">X</label>    
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
            <input type="hidden" id="ProductID" name="ProductID" value="{{productobj.EnID}}" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Productlist" class="control-label col-md-4">Product Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">                
                    <label class="control-label col-md-8">{{productobj.Name}}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Unit Type</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <select ng-change="onUnitChanged(selectedUnitItem)" id="UnitCode" name="UnitCode" ng-model="selectedUnitItem" class="form-control col-md-8">
                      <option ng-repeat="inv in productobj.Inventories track by inv.Code" value="{{inv.Code}}">{{inv.UnitChart.UnitChartName}}  -  Price : {{inv.SellingPrice}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Available Stock</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-8">{{selectedUnitItem.Quantity}}&nbsp;</label>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-4">Order Qty</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                   <input ng-pattern="/^(0|[0-9][0-9]*)$/" type="number" id="Quantity" name="Quantity" class="form-control col-md-8" />
                </div>
            </div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-submit="$ctrl.ok()">Add To Cart</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

ASP.NET Core MVC action methods:

```
[HttpGet] 
public async Task<ActionResult> AddToCart()
{
    return PartialView();
}

[HttpPost] 
public async Task<ActionResult> PostAddToCart(string UnitCode,string ProductID,decimal Quantity)
{
    return PartialView("AddToCart");
}
```

Can anyone explain how to submit popup data to `PostAddToCart`?

Comment: You need to inject the $http service into your **ModalInstanceCtr** so that you can send the http request .

Comment: Thanks, The Problem is solved by updating ModalInstanceCtr like below.     app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $uibModalInstance, product) {
      //code here

       $ctrl.ok = function () {
           $http({
             //Code here
           });
       };  
       });